# Project Name getting appended to Output writer

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

Trying to display a value from database without refreshing the webpage using JQuery and Ajax was successful in displaying this however “Served at: /Project name” is getting appended to the value displayed

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#AESASJOBRUNOPTION').change(function() {
    var AESASJOBRUNOPTION = $('#AESASJOBRUNOPTION').val();      
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',     
      url: "AESASJobCurrentOpenPeriod",
      data: {AESASJOBRUNOPTION: AESASJOBRUNOPTION},
      cache: false,
      success: function(result) {
        $("#result1").html(result);
        $("#result1").html(result).slideDown('slow');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Servlet:

```
try{
  if(ASCOGSRS.next()){
    //System.out.println("Open Peiod is :"+ASCOGSRS.getString(1));
    HttpSession OpenPeriodsession=request.getSession();
    OpenPeriodsession.setAttribute("ASCOGSCurrentOpenPeriod", ASCOGSRS.getString(1));
    PrintWriter out =response.getWriter();
    String ASCOGSOpenPeriod=ASCOGSRS.getString(1);
    out.print(" The Current Open Period is: "+ASCOGSOpenPeriod);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project is using [JET Template](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.1.0/newandnoteworthy/javaee.php) from  Eclipse, looks like the `doPost` method [appends](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=462042) the extra `Served at: <PATH>`.

If JET Template is used, following are possible solutions:

1. Skip using JET Template in Eclipse `Window -> Preferences -> Java EE`
2. If Skipping JET Template is not possible and your AJAX request only retrieves the data, change the request type to `GET` instead of `POST`

If JET Template is not used, following is a solution at the Javascript level:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#AESASJOBRUNOPTION').change(function() {
    var AESASJOBRUNOPTION = $('#AESASJOBRUNOPTION').val();      
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',     
      url: "AESASJobCurrentOpenPeriod",
      data: {AESASJOBRUNOPTION: AESASJOBRUNOPTION},
      cache: false,
      success: function(result) {
        result_without_path = result.replace(/Served at:[\/a-zA-Z0-9]*/i,'');
        $("#result1").html(result_without_path);
        $("#result1").html(result_without_path).slideDown('slow');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also look for response writer in your servlets which may write the response it should be something like:

```
response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
```

And then you can comment this line from your servlet.